# Please explain how this c++ program is working?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble , in understanding this program please help:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
 const char* s = 5+"hellow world";
 cout<<s;
 return 0;
 }
```

It is correct and gives following output[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `5+"hellow world";` is pointer arithmetic. `"hellow world"` is a string literal, a `const char *` so this is the same as  `const char * temp = "hellow world";` followed by `5 + temp;`, which is the same as `&temp[5];`

Comment: If `foo` is a pointer (which is the case here), then `foo + 5` is the same as `5 + foo` and the same as `foo[5]` which is again the same as `5[foo]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In third line of your code, an anonymous character array is created by the compiler. When you add `5` to the c-string, it performs pointer arithmetic and moves the pointer `5` ahead to the string. Hence, it skips the `5` character from the c-string and only stores other characters from the array into the `s`.